# Set default options for find on Linux

Tags: bash, find

I often have other filing systems mounted on my Ubuntu machine, and as a result, when I do a `find`, I have to make sure I include the `-mount` option (which is the same as the `-xdev` option) to avoid it searching (often slowly) on those filing systems too.  Sometimes, however, I forget; then I wonder why the `find` is taking so long!  What I'd like is a way of making `find` use `-mount` all the time.

There doesn't seem to be an [environment variable](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES) I can use, and there doesn't seem to be something like a `.findrc` file where I can specify options.  And I can't easily use an `alias` because `-mount` needs to be after the location(s) I want to search.  I *could* make a `bash` function that takes the arguments for the search and then inserts `-mount` after all the locations but before the first switch before passing it to the `find` command; but before I go to the effort, is there already a way of ensuring `find` uses `-mount` every time it's run?

Comment: The function is the right approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it's useful to anyone else, here the `bash` function I came up with:

```
find () {
  # Make a copy of the arguments so they can be altered
  local args=("$@")
  # Will start to look at the first (zeroth) element
  local i=0
  # While element i exists and doesn't start with a "-", increment i
  while [[ $i -lt ${#args[@]} && ${args[$i]} != -* ]]; do
    let ++i
  done
  # Insert -mount at position i, which is where the first switch currently is
  # (or is the end of the argument list).
  args=("${args[@]:0:$i}" '-mount' "${args[@]:$i}")
  # Use env to locate the find command in the path, and pass the manipulated
  # arguments to it.
  env find "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: i think you should accept your own answer. it's good stuff